# How to calculate the grand total of the column only condition that the contents?

Tags: javascript

sorry if I ask about things that are similar to before, but I've tried and confused in coding javascipt.
As before I want to calculate the Grand total with the condition that only isNaN will be = 0 and if not NaN = total. When i try condition isNaN it's correct but if not NaN he keep total = 0 why?? i already try with onKeyup, onBlur, and onChange maybe i have wrong in function? Can help me please?

```
<html>
<head>
    <form method = "POST" action="text.php" name="form">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function cal1() {
    var a = parseInt($(".qty1").val());
    var b = parseInt($(".price1").val());
    var c1 = a * b; //a * b
    $(".total1").val(c1);
    grandtotal();
    }

    function cal2() {
    var a = parseInt($(".qty2").val());
    var b = parseInt($(".price2").val());
    var c2 = a * b; //a * b
    $(".total2").val(c2);
    grandtotal();
    }

    function cal3() {
    var a = parseInt($(".qty3").val());
    var b = parseInt($(".price3").val());
    var c3 = a * b; //a * b
    $(".total3").val(c3);
    grandtotal();
    }

    function grandtotal() {
    var a1 = parseInt($(".total1").val());
    var b1 = parseInt($(".total2").val());
    var c1 = parseInt($(".total3").val());
    if (isNaN(a1.value) == true)
    {
        var a1=0;
    }
    else
    {
        var a1 = parseInt($(".total1").val());
    }
    if (isNaN(b1.value) == true)
    {
        var b1=0;
    }
    else
    {
        var b1 = parseInt($(".total2").val());
    }
    if (isNaN(c1.value) == true)
    {
        var c1=0;
    }
    else
    {
        var c1 = parseInt($(".total3").val());
    }
    var z = a1+b1+c1; // a1+b1+c1
    $(".grandtotal").val(z);
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body>



<table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table height="51" border="0" cellspacing="2">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div align="center">Price</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div align="center"> Total Price</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>

                                <td>
                                    <input  class="qty1"  type="text" name="qty1" onblur="qty_blur(this);" onkeyup="cal1();" value="">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input  class="price1"  type="text" name="price1" onblur="price_blur(this);" onkeyup="cal1();" value="">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input  class="total1"  type="text" name="total1" value="0" readonly=true onkeyup="grandtotal();">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input  class="qty2"  type="text" name="qty2" onblur="qty_blur(this);" onkeyup="cal2();" value="">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input  class="price2"  type="text" name="price2" onblur="price_blur(this);" onkeyup="cal2();" value="">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input  class="total2"  type="text" name="total2" value="0" readonly=true onkeyup="grandtotal();">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input  class="qty3"  type="text" name="qty3" onblur="qty_blur(this);" onkeyup="cal3();" value="">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input  class="price3"  type="text" name="price3" onblur="price_blur(this);" onkeyup="cal3();" value="">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input  class="total3"  type="text" name="total3" value="0" readonly=true onkeyup="grandtotal();">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tr div class="grandtotal">
                    <td>
                        Grand Total :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="grandtotal" name="grandtotal" type="text" readonly=true value="">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </div>
            </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers don't have a `.value` property; just check the number itself. Also, `isNaN` returns a Boolean, so you don't need to check `== true`.

```
if (isNaN(a1)) {
    var a1=0;
}
```